# What all are still Unproven Conjectures in Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, soft-question, conjectures

I know that Goldbach's conjecture is yet to be proved even though it has been [shown to hold up through](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Goldbach's_conjecture) $4 \times10^{18}$. I haven't been able to find a comprehensive list of unproven conjectures on google.There is a list of unsolved problems, list of conjectures but not that of unproven ones.I am interested in knowing if some conjectures(related to Number Theory), that are yet unproven, are still extensively used while arriving at solutions of mathematical problems.

Comment: Twin prime conjecture, $3n+1$ conjecture, prime between every pair of consecutive squares conjecture.

Comment: Making a list of *all* conjectures is a pointless task, really. To turn this into a sensible question, you could try to make it more focused or something, but drafting random lists that in principle could include hundreds of items is not going to be of any use.

Comment: It could serve as a reference. "Cataloging" and Mathematics go hand in hand and it is an age-old practice. In a way Hilbert did the same when he proposed 23 problems.

Comment: I am sorry but I see absolutely no connection between your question and Hilbert's list… He was putting to the fore problems he thought would shape the future of mathematics, not making a list of random things (and, well, he was Hilbert, which is not a minor detail). On the other hand, Math.SE is a terribly bad medium for cataloguing anything —it does not even provide a sensible way to sort things.

Comment: I agree with you completely and it makes perfect sense that Math.SE is a bad choice for such a purpose. Also Hilbert, Euclid  are beyond comparison . Anyways I'll throw it open to the community to decide the fate of this question.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I personally like this question since it leaves open the possibility for interesting discussion about interesting problems for those who want to discuss interesting things.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut, if anything, that makes it worse: this site is not a place for discussions and, in fact, it is extraordinarily bad for them.

Comment: I just digged in a bit on this site and there are many questions which have many answers and are generally broad , like the one on beauty in mathematics, visually stunning math concepts or be it the list of mathematicians more famous for conjectures than theorems. Anyways this is definitely my last question out here on this site.

Comment: I hope that you think tomorrow in a different way, I would like to encourage to you. Mathematics are very nice. I've *some* questions as recent deleted questions. And also one question as [closed]. Tomorrow is a new day, and I know that this site, and all users can help me a lot.

Comment: Ok done, will try !!

Comment: There exists a conjecture that for all natural $n \geqslant 91$, you can align all numbers from $1$ to $n$ in a row so that each adjacent pair adds up to a squared number. There are other exceptions as well, nonetheless. We can consider the case where $n = 17$ and one has: $$17 - 8 - 1 - 15 - 10 - 6 - 3 - 13 - 12 - 4 - 5 - 11 - 14 - 2 - 7 - 9 - 16$$ But when you consider $n = 18, 19, 20, 21$ or $22$ then it is impossible to create this alignment, until you consider $n = 23$. Go here to answer your question $\rightarrow$ https://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0010/0010143.pdf

Answer (score 5):

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics) lists most of the important ones. It's how I first got interested in research mathematics. All of the ones listed in the main body of the page are unproven so far.

In terms of the ones that are used a lot by mathematicians, I would have to say that the Riemann Hypothesis is on top, as it is quoted that "Entire books are written assuming the Riemann Hypothesis" (I think that's Derbyshire).

Answer (score 3):

One I recently discovered is the conjecture that all perfect numbers are even. The first $10^{300}$ natural numbers have been checked, and all perfect numbers in that range are even.

Comment: Well since every perfect number is of the form $2^{p - 1}(2^p - 1)$ then of course it is going to be even, having $2$ as an aliquot divisor. It follows, then, that all we need to prove is that every perfect number *must* have this form in order to be perfect in the first place. If we cannot prove that, then there exists an odd perfect number out there that is greater than $10^{300}$

Comment: @Mr Pie: Your comment could not be worse, without losing its veneer of knowledgeability, if you tried. To start with, it is not true that every perfect number has that form, but that every EVEN perfect number has that form. That numbers of that form are perfect was proved by Euclid. That every EVEN perfect number must be of that form was proved by Euler. Then, worst of all, you conflate our ability to find a proof with the existence of a proof.

Comment: @EulerSpoiler oh.